# Analysis: If$\int_a^bf(x)dx\le\int_a^bg(x)dx$, is it true $ f(c)\le g(c)$ for some $c\in [a,b]?$

Tags: real-analysis

***If the integral of $f(x)$ is $\le$ the integral of $g(x)$ on [a,b], is it true f(c) $\le$ than g(c) for some c on [a,b]?***

Please let me know if this is correct:

By the starting conditions,

The integral of $g(x)-f(x)$ is $\ge$ 0 on [a,b]

As the integral is the area under the curve, the Riemann Sum

[image]

The area under the curve is the height times the distance.

[image: Interval] (The distance of the interval is always greater than 0).

Thus there are 2 cases:

***Case Number 1:***

$f(x) \le g(x)$ on all the interval [a,b]

***Case Number 2:***

$f(x) \le g(x)$ on most of the interval and $f(x) > g(x)$ on some subintervals. If not, the integral of $g(x)-f(x) \not\ge 0$.

***Either case it is true that $f(c)$ $\le$ than $g(c)$ for some c on [a,b] Q.E.D.***

Comment: Yes because the integral of a positive function is positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not (and I assume we are talking about Riemann integrals here), then $h(x) = f(x) - g(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and using Riemann sums you can show that for all $c_1,c_2 \in [a,b]$ 
$$\int_{c_1}^{c_2} h(x) \, dx \geqslant 0.$$

Since this is not a strict inequality, we have not yet contradicted the hypothesis.

Since $h$ is Riemann integrable, there exists a point $t$ where $h$ is continuous. Thus, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $h(x) > h(t)/2 > 0$ for all $x \in [t-\delta,t+\delta] \subset [a,b].$ It follows that

$$\int_a^bh(x) \,dx \geqslant \int_{t-\delta}^{t+\delta} h(x) \, dx > h(t)\delta > 0.$$

This does contradict the hypothesis. Therefore, there must be a point where $f(c) \leqslant g(c).$

Comment: Great ideas! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove that if $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)$ satisfies $\int_a^b hdx\geq 0$, then there exists $c\in[a,b]$ such that $h(c)\geq 0$ by linearity of the integral. By contradiction, assume $g(x)<0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Then by the definition, for any tagged partition $\mathcal{P}=\{a=x_0<x_1<\dots<x_n=b, t_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]\:i\in[1,n]\}$, we have $$R(\mathcal{P})=\sum_{i=1}^n h(t_i)(x_{i}-x_{{i-1}})<0\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$Since $x_i-x_{i-1}>0$ and $h(t_i)<0$, so each term of the sum is less than $0$, and thus there sum is also less than $0$.

Now we consider two scenarios: $\int_a^b hdx>0$ and $\int_a^bhdx=0$. Let $s=\int_a^bhdx$. By definition, the integral is defined if, $\forall \epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ and a tagged partition $\mathcal{P}$ such that $\max(x_{i}-x_{i-1})<\delta$ and $$|R(\mathcal{P})-s|<\epsilon\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$ In the first case, $s>0$, choose $\epsilon=s/2$. Then the above condition implies $$R(\mathcal{P})>-\epsilon+s=s/2>0$$which contradicts (1). Now suppose $s=0$. It suffices to prove the negation of (2), which is basically the statement that $R(\mathcal{P})$ cannot get too close to $0$. Since $h$ is Riemann integrable, it is bounded, so $\max(h)<M$ for some $M< 0$. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be any tagged partition. Then $$R(\mathcal{P})=\sum_{i=1}^n h(t_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})\leq M\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-x_{i-1})= M(b-a)$$because the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1})$ is telescoping. So let $\epsilon=-M(b-a)/2$. Then we can find no partition such that $R(\mathcal{P})\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ by the argument I just made (work out the details if you don't see it). So this contradicts integrability, and thus there is $c\in [a,b]$ such that $h(c)\geq 0$.

Edit: As noted in the comments (and a detail I attempted to skirt past), that $h(x)<0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ does not imply $\sup_{[a,b]}h=M<0$. It could be that $M=0$, in which case my argument doesn't work. In that scenario, using an argument that the function is continuous at some point is probably best. I was trying to do this primarily from the definition.

Edit 2: So it is possible to do this without appealing to continuity, according to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/574684/192336). However, their definition of the Riemann integral is much easier to use for this purpose, but it must be possible here as well.

Comment: How do you know there exists $M$ such that $h(x) < M < 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$? What if $M = 0$ is the least upper bound.

Comment: Yeah I kind of fudged that one. I was trying to go off of first principles without trying to appeal to a continuity result. I'll think about how to fix that.

Comment: The problem is that an integral is a supremum (infimum) of lower (upper) sums. Even if $f(x) >0$ without more information we can only conclude $\int_a^b f \geqslant 0.$  Without continuity $f(x) > 0$ only implies $\inf_{[x_{j-1},x_j]} f(x) \geqslant 0 \implies L(P,f) \geqslant 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume not. g=f-e where e is strictly positive.Then the integral of g is the integral of f minus the integral of e . But e is positive so the integral of g is less than the integral of f.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you!