# if $f$ Riemann integrable then has a continuity point.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Prove that if $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a Riemann integrable function. Using the Nested Cantor Intervals Theorem, prove that there exist $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f$ is continuous in $c$

Comment: Nice exercise. What did you try?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515926/f-in-mathscr-ra-b-implies-f-has-infinitely-many-points-of-continuity/519921#519921).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $f$ is continuous at $c$ if 
$$
\lim_{\delta\to 0} \left[
\max_{x \in [c-\delta,c+\delta]} f(x)
- \min_{x \in [c-\delta,c+\delta]} f(x)
\right] = 0
$$