# An integrable nowhere continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to construct a nowhere continuous function while it is Riemann integrable. There's a nowhere differentiable while continuous function, but I don't know about the latter one?

Comment: No such function exists. For bounded functions defined on a closed interval, they are Riemann integrable iff they're continuous a.e.

Comment: It is possible to prove (without using measure theory) that a Riemann integrable function must be continuous at some point in the interval and hence continuous at some point in every subinterval. See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/519921/72031

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. [Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability) says that a bounded function is Riemann-integrable if and only if it is continuous except on a null set.

Comment: Is there a simple counterexample to the same statement but with Lebesgue integrable functions? Ie. is there a function that is Lebesgue integrable but not continuous on any set of co-measure 0? (Feel free to assume the function is bounded and the domain is compact, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Riemann integration is too weak for this, there is a theorem which states that it is Riemann integrable when the discontinuities are at most 
countable or in a set of measure zero, so nowhere continuous is too strong.

For Lebesgue integral, $1_{\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q}$ is nowhere continuous but integrable (of value $b-a$ on $[a,b]$).