# Proving that if $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a, b]$, then cardinality of set of points of continuity on $[a, b]$ is equal to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, continuity, riemann-integration

I'm given a theorem:

> Let $f$ be Riemann-integrable on $[a, b]$. Then in $[a, b]$ it has infinitely many points of continuity.

Which is proven by using Riemann sums and constructing sequence of intervals $[a, b] \supset [a_1, b_1] \supset ...$ which converges to some point $c$ and then proving continuity from definition.

Now, there is second theorem:

> Let $f$ be Riemann-integrable on $[a, b]$. Then in $[a, b]$ cardinality of set of points of continuity is equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

Where proof is stated as "Variation of previous one". How can I show that cardinality of set of points of continuity is equal to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What does "continuous in continuum" mean?

Comment: @carmichael561 my error, I mean its cardinality is equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ok, so you mean the set of $x\in[a,b]$ at which $f$ is continuous has the cardinality of the continuum?

Comment: Proving that the set of discontinuities has measure 0 should do it.

Comment: "Variation on previous one" - How much choice so you have in picking your subintervals there?

Comment: I made a mistake - theorem spoke about "Then in $[a,b]$ cardinality of set of points of continuity is equal to $\mathbb{R}$". I'm really sorry for this mistake.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability

Comment: The set of continuities of a riemann integrable function $f$ is $[a,b]\setminus X$ where $X$ is the set of discontinuities which has finite limit points which implies $X$ is countable. Now, removing countable number of elements from an infinite set doesn't change its cardinality, so the cardinality is $|[a,b]\setminus X|=|[a,b]|$. Since there is a bijection from $[a,b]$ to $\Bbb R$, we arrive at our conclusion.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas No, $X$  could be the Cantor set.

Comment: @AcceleratetotheInfinity Your last sentence needs editing. It doesn't make sense as stated.

Comment: What we're missing is the proof of the first theorem. This is a novel approach to certain results many here at MSE know, but we know through a different line of thought.

Comment: @zhw.: First theorem is proved at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/519921/72031