# Direct Proof that a bounded, everywhere discontinuous function is not Riemann Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I'm trying to construct a direct (that is, using properties of Riemann Integration and/or the partition definition of the Riemann Integral) prove that if a bounded function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is discontinuous at every point on its domain, then it is not Riemann Integrable.

My initial approach has been to show that

$\exists \epsilon >0$ s.t. for all partitions $P$ of $[a,b]$,

$U(f,P)-L(f,P) \geq \epsilon$

I know this can be seen as a consequence that the interval $[a,b]$ has nonzero measure, so $f$ does not satisfy Lebesgue's criterion. However, how can I go about constructing such an epsilon for a general function f?

Comment: Show instead that if  $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is Riemann integrable there must exist at least one point of continuity.  If Hankel could do it in 1870 you can do it in 2021.  Use Riemann's criterion and a nested sequence of intervals.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson could you please clarify how to go about this? I don't understand how I could prove that the point in the intersection of those intervals would be continuous

Comment: Check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/519921/72031) which proves that a Riemann integrable function must be continuous somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

*Nobody jumping in to help so far ...*

Here is a method you might like.  At least it will give you some insight into continuity, if not the Riemann integral.

**Preliminaries.**  There is some nice stuff to know about continuity.  Let  $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be an arbitrary function.  Define

$$ \phi(x,\delta) = \sup \{ |f(s)-f(t)|: s,t \in [a,b]\cap (x-\delta,x+\delta)\} $$
and

$$\phi(x) = \inf_{\delta>0} \phi(x,\delta).$$

Then

1. $\phi(x)=0$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $x$.
2. Each set  $E_n= \{x\in [a,b]:\phi(x)\geq \frac1n\}$ is closed.
3. The set of points of discontinuity of the function $f$ is the union $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ of this sequence of closed sets.
4. If $f$ is everywhere discontinuous one of these sets must contain a subinterval of $[a,b]$.

These are relatively elementary.  For (1)-(3) see **Section 6.7.2 The Set of Continuity Points** in reference **[1].**  For (4) you need to know that no interval can be expressed as the union of a sequence of closed sets that are nowhere dense (i.e., none of them contain an interval).  This is easy to prove using nested sequences of intervals.  See **Section 6.3 Nowhere Dense Sets** in reference **[1]** if you wish to pursue this topic further  (or any text that covers the Baire category theorem).

---

Now to prove our theorem:

**Theorem.  Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be discontinuous at each point.
Then $f$ is not Riemann integrable.**

**Lemma.  Suppose that $f:[c,d]\to\mathbb R$ has the property that
$\phi(x)\geq \delta>0$ for every $c<x<d$.  Then $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $[c,d]$.**

This is particularly easy to prove from the elementary methods of the Riemann or Darboux integral.  In fact your comments above about your "initial apporoach" will work here.

*Proof of theorem.*  If $f$ is everywhere discontinuous then one of the sets $E_n$ defined above must contain an subinterval $[c,d]$ of $[a,b]$.  By the lemma the function $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $[c,d]$ and hence cannot be integrable on $[a,b]$.

---

**Other methods?**

(a) Most students of mathematics are likely to respond this way:  "Every Riemann integrable function must be continuous almost everywhere (as proved by Lebesgue) so of course this is true."  See **Section 8.6.3 Lebesgue’s Criterion** of reference **[1]** for an accessible proof.

(b) Most 19th century mathematicians would have responded like this (since they had no notion of almost everywhere or measure zero sets):  "If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ then for every integer $n$ the set  $E_n= \{x\in [a,b]:\phi(x)\geq \frac1n\}$
is a closed set of zero Peano-Jordan content.  The set of discontinuities is the union of this sequence and that cannot be all of $[a,b]$."

(In fact Lebesgue's criterion is a nearly trivial extension of the 19th century version.)

(c) A direct proof (already suggested) is to use Riemann's criterion and a nested sequence of intervals to uncover one point of continuity.  The user Paramandand Singh supplied this link for those details:
[$f \in {\mathscr R[a,b]} \implies f $ has infinitely many points of continuity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515926/f-in-mathscr-ra-b-implies-f-has-infinitely-many-points-of-continuity/519921#519921)

---

**REFERENCE:**

**[1]**   https://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf